# Read CSV and plot colored line graph

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, graph, plot

I am trying to plot a graph with colored markers before and after threshold value. If I am using for loop `for` reading the parsing the input file with time `H:M` I can plot and color only two points. But for all the points I cannot plot.

Input

```
akdj 12:00 34515 sdfg
sgqv 13:00 34626 ssfgb
dfbb 13:00 14215 gghgws
ajdf 13:30 14224 gdgva
dsfb 13:45 25672 FW 
sfhh 14:00 85597 adsfb
```

program

```
# ma masked array
import csv
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import  plot

threshold = 30000
x,y = [],[]
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('Count_Time.csv'))

for line in csv_reader:
    y.append(int(line[2]))
    x.append(dt.datetime.strptime(line[1],'%H:%M'))

#plt.figure()

plt.plot(x,y, color='blue')

#Add below threshold markers
below_threshold = y < threshold
plt.scatter(x[below_threshold], y[below_threshold], color='green') 

# Add above threshold markers
above_threshold = np.logical_not(below_threshold)
plt.scatter(x[above_threshold], y[above_threshold], color='red')


plt.show()
```

Wrong Output

[image]

When I used the below code to read file that did not show any error but showed a blank graph layout.

```
data = np.genfromtxt('Count_Time.csv', delimiter=",")
x = data[:,1]
y = data[:,2]
```

When changed this way following error is shown

```
data = np.loadtxt('Count_Time.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='str, time, int, str')
x = data[:,1]
y = data[:,2]
```

Error

```
 data = np.loadtxt('Count_Time.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='str, time, int, str')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 798, in loadtxt
    dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: data type "time" not understood
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to turn `x` and `y` into type `np.array` before you calculate `above_threshold` and `below_threshold`, and then it works. In your version, you don't get an array of bools, but just `False` and `True`.

I added comma delimiters to your input csv file to make it work (I assume the should be there in the first place?)

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import  plot

threshold = 30000
x,y = [],[]
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('input.csv'))

for line in csv_reader:
    y.append(int(line[2]))
    x.append(dt.datetime.strptime(line[1],'%H:%M'))

fig=plt.figure()

below_threshold = y < threshold
above_threshold = np.logical_not(below_threshold)

print below_threshold
# False

print above_threshold
# True

x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)

plt.plot(x,y, color='blue')

#Add below threshold markers
below_threshold = y < threshold
print below_threshold
# [False False  True  True  True False]

plt.scatter(x[below_threshold], y[below_threshold], color='green') 

# Add above threshold markers
above_threshold = np.logical_not(below_threshold)
print above_threshold
# [ True  True False False False  True]

plt.scatter(x[above_threshold], y[above_threshold], color='red')

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great .. Thanks this works awesome for me.. I need to put `plt.autofmt_xdate()` that give me some error.

Comment: `autofmt_xdate` is a method of `plt.figure`, so you need to have `fig=plt.figure` and then `fig.autofmt_xdate()` (see my edit above)

Comment: Thank you so much .. one last query how can I have legends for colored markers. `plt.legend` doesn't work

Comment: you just need to give your `plt.scatter` plot a `label`. e.g. `plt.scatter(x[below_threshold], y[below_threshold], color='green',label='below')` before you call `plt.legend()`