# Read One Input File and plot multiple

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, plot

I am trying to read one input file of below format. Where `Col[1]` is x axis and `Col[2]` is y axis and `col[3]` is some name. I need to plot multiple line graphs for separate names of `col[3]`. Eg: Name `sd` with `x,y`  values will have one line graph and name `gg` with relative `x,y` values will have another line graph. All in one output image but separate graphs. Is it possible with Python Matplotlib ? Pls do redirect me to any example. I have already checked couldn't find any.

```
akdj 12:00 34515 sd
sgqv 13:00 34626 sd
dfbb 13:00 14215 gg
ajdf 13:30 14224 gg
dsfb 13:45 25672 FW 
sfhh 14:00 85597 ad
```

Thanks for valuable suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the condition `z=='some tag'` to index the `x` and `y` array

Here's an example (based on the code in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841038/read-csv-and-plot-colored-line-graph)) that should do it. Use a set to automate the creation of tags:

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

threshold = 30000
x,y,z = [],[],[]
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('input.csv'))

for line in csv_reader:
    y.append(int(line[2]))
    x.append(dt.datetime.strptime(line[1],'%H:%M'))
    z.append(line[3])

x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)

tags = list(set(z))
z=np.array(z)

fig=plt.figure()

for tag in tags:
    plt.plot(x[z==tag],y[z==tag],'o-',label=tag)

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.legend(loc=2)

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Tom .. Thank you again .. But ss or gd were only examples.. the input files will have many such rows. Of-course we cannot mention all of them as list. Is thr any option to automatically identify?

Comment: And I guess you understood well ..my intention is to merge the two and also  annotate with something like this .. The names like `ss` `gd` are to be annotated on marker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147112/matplotlib-how-to-put-individual-tags-for-a-scatter-plot?rq=1

Comment: you could use a python `set` to get all the unique tags in your file. For example `list(set(z))` above would return `['sd','gg','FW','ad']`. Then, you could loop over that new list, and create a condition for each one. I've edited the answer to do just this.

Comment: You are just wow .. if you can please help me with this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832216/heat-map-annotation-with-text